# How to convert XmlNodeList to xml file?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I am trying to convert a XmlNodeList to an xml file in c# code.

I have created xml document, retrieved from it a list of elements, and now I wish to convert that list to xml file.

```
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("MyXmlFile.xml");

XmlNodeList contactList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Contact");
```

My next step is to convert my XmlNodeList to xml file.
How do I do that?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the xml structure?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("MyXmlFile.xml");

            XmlNodeList contactList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Contact");
            SaveToFile(contactList);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }           
    }            

    static void SaveToFile(XmlNodeList nodeList)
    {
        var xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        xmlBuilder.Append("<Contacts>");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            xmlBuilder.Append(node.OuterXml);
        }

        xmlBuilder.Append("</Contacts>");

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlBuilder.ToString());
        doc.Save("contacts.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do keep it short as

```
XmlNodeList contactList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Contact");
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(fileName))
{
  writer.WriteLine($"<Root>{string.Join("",contactList.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x=>x.OuterXml))}</Root>");  
}
```